# I want to get system date format using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to format date format.

current format
2020-03-04T18:30:00.000+0000

required format
2020-03-04

I am trying to do it using as below, but its not expected one

```
 <td style="width:12%">{{bank.createDate.replace("T", " ").replace(".000+0000", "") }}</td>
```

can u help me to do it.

Comment: found date:'yyyy-MM-dd'

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pipe operator that AngularJs provides for you this is the link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

```
{{ date_expression | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

But in your case it will be

```
 <td style="width:12%">{{bank.createDate | | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
```